# apply a permutation to a 1D tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, permutation, composition

I would like to make the following node :

```
a=tf.variable([2,0,1,4,3])      (a permutation)
b=tf.variable([11,12,13,14,15])
```

How to have

```
c="b[a]"=tf.variable([13,11,12,15,14])
```

?

Answer (score 3):

I found an other way to solve my question, I think it is a good one : (`tf.gather`)

```
a = [2,0,1,4,3]
b = tf.constant([11,12,13,14,15])
c=tf.gather(b,a)
print(sess.run(c))
```

it gives `[12 13 11 14 15]` so that is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there's no `permute` function for tensors. And you can't iterate over the elements in a tensor or variable. Here's the closest I can come up with:

```
a = [2,0,1,4,3]
b = tf.constant([11,12,13,14,15])
b_vecs = tf.unstack(b)
b_new = [b_vecs[index] for index in a]
c = tf.stack(b_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a (pseudo)random permutation is acceptable for your application, the permutation could be performed using bumpy:

```
import python as np
arr=np.array([11,12,13,14,15])
np.random.shuffle(arr)
c=tf.Variable(arr)
```